# Help with a question about Integral test for convergence.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> Use the Integral test and determine Convergence or Divergence $$\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{n^{k-1}}{n^k+c}$$

Let $f\left(x\right) = \dfrac{x^{k-1}}{x^k+c}$

Now I have to find when the first derivative is less than zero.

$f^{\prime}\left(x\right) = \dfrac{\left(k-1\right)x^{k-2}\left(x^{k}+c\right)-kx^{k-1}x^{k-1}}{\left(x^k+c\right)^2} < 0$

this is where I get lost, any hints how to finish this?

Comment: Hint: they call it the *integral* test because it involves the integral (not the derivative).

Comment: @gerry Myerson, yes I know that but one of the requirements is that it the first derivative be decreasing for $x \geq 1$, and the function be positive, and continuous.

Comment: umm, i think f'(x) is wrong, we need to write constant c part, so i edit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f^{\prime}\left(x\right) = \dfrac{\left(k-1\right)x^{k-2}x^{k}-kx^{k-1}x^{k-1}}{\left(x^k+c\right)^2} =\dfrac{\left(k-1\right)x^{2k-2}-kx^{2k-2}}{\left(x^k+c\right)^2}=\dfrac{x^{2k-2}(\left(k-1\right)-k)}{\left(x^k+c\right)^2}=\dfrac{-x^{2k-2}}{\left(x^k+c\right)^2}< 0$

Now, Denominator is perfect square , hence positive and $x^{2k-2}$ is always positive too since power is even and therefore $f'(x)$ is always $<0$ unless $x=0$.

Comment: I kept trying to expand out the powers, I now see where I went astray. Thanks.

Comment: i am glad i could help :)